# How to speed up the disposal of a ListView

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

How can I speed up the disposal of a ListView control?

A little background: this solution is using MaterialSkin, so my list of available controls is limited (there is no ListBox or DataGridView, for example).  Second, the list has an unreasonably large number of items (51k on average, one or two columns, depending on settings), so I'm not expecting lightning speeds, but also not what I'm seeing.

When the form is closing, I don't need anything from the list.  It's served its purpose and can just go away.  Here is what I've tried:

```
Close();                    --- 16 seconds (just closing the form)

MyListView.Dispose();       --- 16 seconds

MyListView.Items.Clear();   --- 16 seconds

MyListView.Clear();         --- 17 seconds

MyListView.BeginUpdate();
MyListView.Items.Clear();   --- 16 seconds
```

Effectively, every option I've tried is ~16 seconds to get rid of the list.  Now, it takes about 16 seconds to populate the list, something I'm also looking into -- but at least there the time is somewhat justified in that I'm overloading this poor list with too many records.  And there, I know the ListView has to deal with the overhead of placing items.  In removal, not so much.

Note: form is being displayed with ShowDialog -- so control isn't returned until the 16 seconds are up.  A fall-back plan is to use Show and trigger an event when the dialog is in the process of closing.

And yes, I think displaying 51k records is bad UI, and have explained that to the client multiple times; for now, the insistence that 51k records be there stands. (I did add a full text search, otherwise...)

Comment: What happens if you try the same data loading with a bog standard `ListView`? My guess is performance will be as you expect. Anyway, MaterialSkin is dead: https://github.com/IgnaceMaes/MaterialSkin#state-of-the-project you should move on to a UI framework that is supported and offers all the controls you need, e.g. DevExpress. You will have to pay, but you will get controls that actually perform properly.

Comment: Interesting thought.  Tried swapping out the control.  Same performance -- but that does answer a question I had yesterday, so worth the try.

Comment: The ListView Control has a Virtual Mode that lets you load items from a source only when these items are actually shown. An example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61719931/7444103)

Comment: I've never noticed the Virtual Mode before -- promising.  I need to rejigger my code some for that, but initial tests had a much faster disposal.  I'll play with this some more.

Comment: When you do, if you have added your ListView in the Form Designer, you don't need to dispose of the ListView Items, you need to dispose of the source objects.

Comment: Using the virtual method, instead of ~16s on load and ~16s on close, I'm now 1-3s on load and 500ms on close.  It brings a lot of quirks along with it (how I handle selections and making sure I don't go past the end of my data, etc.), but the speed is well worth the other changes. Have most things functioning again at a much more reasonable speed.  And the client gets their 51k records.

Comment: Selections are the same and, if you have followed the code I linked (read the notes there), you'll see that it's really hard to read past your source Min/Max bounds, since you're the one providing the Items in `RetrieveVirtualItem` and (eventually) `SearchForVirtualItem`. So the control on the source items is all in your hands. You cannot fail (you know the source bounds and, usually, you won't be asked for an items that's not there. Anyway, you always check whether the `e.ItemIndex` requested falls within those bound - especially the lower bound, since `e.ItemIndex` **can** be `< 0`).

Comment: You should post virtual mode as an answer @Jimi - I completely forgot about that one.

Comment: @Ian Kemp I think I've already explained everything in that post I linked. It includes the base Virtual Mode functionality, standard item retrieval, search functionality - which also build the `SelectedIndexes` collection. I should repeat the ~same code and notes here. Or focus on the MaterialSkin implementation: you noted that is not maintained, but it's worse than that: the ListView is owner-drawn and that code leaks already; in case of an exception, none of the graphics object is ever disposed of. It goes on like that for all custom controls. But I don't really want to talk about this.

Comment: @Jimi Then would you say this question should be closed as a dupe of the other one?

Comment: @Ian Kemp Marked as such. Unless the OP add details specific to the collection they're handling or change the question to a more *focused* one. But, in this case, a new question is probably better, IMO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the Items of a Virtual ListView that are not visible don't have index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61715611/why-the-items-of-a-virtual-listview-that-are-not-visible-dont-have-index)

Answer (score 0):

How about just hiding your listview? Try setting it's visible property to false and when you don't need listview anymore try to close form without clearing your listview

Comment: Had hopes on that -- unfortunately, still comes in at 16 seconds.  Adding edit up above, this form is being displayed with ShowDialog, so control isn't returned until the time is up.  A fall-back is going to be to use Show and events.

Comment: Have you tried using Backgroundworker? Unfortunately i can't help you with that as i havent tried it yet, but it might be the thing you're looking for

Comment: The BackgroundWorker may be where I end up going with this.  It's a good thought.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using databinding instead of using the Listview.Items directly?
So you can set the ItemsSource to null and then (async?) empty the actual List.