# SelectedItems.Count exception in listview with VirtualMode

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

after selecting a value out of my listview and clicking my button i wanted to get my value into the Code but my code is throwing this exception:

> Count = 'this.listView1.SelectedItems.Count' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

```
private void OK_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      try
      {
        // OK -> Daten übernehmen
        ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection data = this.listView1.SelectedItems;

        int iCount = data.Count;
        if (iCount != 1)
        {
          MessageBox.Show("Value is empty");
          return;
        }
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        Close();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        //WriteProtokoll(ex.ToString(), 0);   
        Close();
      }
    }
  }
```

```
 private void listView1_SearchForVirtualItem(object sender, SearchForVirtualItemEventArgs e)
    {
      e.Index = Array.FindIndex(myData, s => s == textBox1.Text.ToString());
    }

    private void listView1_RetrieveVirtualItem(object sender, RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs e)
    {

      e.Item = new ListViewItem(myData[e.ItemIndex]);
     
    }
```

```
    myData = new string[dataListSize];
      for (int i = 0; i < dataListSize; i++)
      {
        myData[i] = String.Format("{0}", i);
      }


 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      String MyString = textBox1.Text.ToString();  

      ListViewItem lvi = listView1.FindItemWithText(MyString.TrimEnd());
      //Select the item found and scroll it into view.
      if (lvi != null)
      {
        listView1.SelectedIndices.Clear();
        listView1.SelectedIndices.Add(lvi.Index);
        listView1.EnsureVisible(lvi.Index);

      }
    }
```

Comment: [Why the Items of a Virtual ListView that are not visible don't have index?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61719931/7444103) -- See the notes, the `RetrieveVirtualItem` and `SearchForVirtualItem` handlers and the code to search for an item in the *virtual* list (`FindItemWithText()`).

Comment: @Jimi I cant still get my value after selecting my value in my listview my **RetrieveVirtualItem** and **SearchForVirtualItem** handlers working fine but after I selected the value and click OK I can not save it into a value to use it further in my Code.

Comment: @Ahmet that problem doesn't seem related to the problem you set out in this question. Perhaps you want to ask a new question on the site?

Comment: @Llama https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68953314/cant-get-my-value-in-listview-virtualmode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design when you use `VirutalMode`. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode?view=net-5.0#remarks) states:

> In virtual mode, the Items collection is disabled. *Attempting to access it results in an InvalidOperationException.* **The same is true of** the CheckedItems collection and **the SelectedItems collection**.

We can confirm this in the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListView.cs,7352).

It goes on to provide the following advice:

> If you want to retrieve the selected or checked items, use the SelectedIndices and CheckedIndices collections instead.

You should therefore use `this.listView1.SelectedIndices.Count` instead.

Looking at the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListView.cs,6987) again, we can see that this won't throw an exception.

Comment: @LIama thanks this worked but cant still get my Value out in my OK_button_Click coudnt use  List.FindIndex()  FindItem() or listView1.FindItemWithText() maybe im to stupid

Comment: my Textbox **textBox1_TextChanged ** calls my **SearchforItem**:

but my OK_Button_click has no Argument to user FindItemWithText

Comment: @Ahmet since it solved your problem, feel free to mark my answer as accepted.