# cant get my Value in Listview Virtualmode

Tags: c#, listview, virtualmode

after clicking my value and pressing my OK_button I cant get the Value out of the listView to save it somewhere else. I cant use listView1.FindItemWithText because I don't have a text to search for.. Idk how to look for the clicked value after I pressed the OK_button

```
      //Create dummy data to display
      myData = new string[dataListSize];
      for (int i = 0; i < dataListSize; i++)
      {
        myData[i] = String.Format("{0}", i);
      }
    }

    private void listView1_SearchForVirtualItem(object sender, SearchForVirtualItemEventArgs e)
    {
      e.Index = Array.FindIndex(myData, s => s == textBox1.Text.ToString());
    }

    private void listView1_RetrieveVirtualItem(object sender, RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs e)
    {
      e.Item = new ListViewItem(myData[e.ItemIndex]);     
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      String MyString = textBox1.Text.ToString();  
      ListViewItem lvi = listView1.FindItemWithText(MyString.TrimEnd());
      //Select the item found and scroll it into view.
      if (lvi != null)
      {
        listView1.SelectedIndices.Clear();
        listView1.SelectedIndices.Add(lvi.Index);
        listView1.EnsureVisible(lvi.Index);
      }
    }

    private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){  }

    private void OK_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      try
      {
        // OK -> Daten übernehmen          
        int iCount = this.listView1.SelectedIndices.Count;
        if (iCount != 1)
        {       
          MessageBox.Show("Value is empty");
          return;
        }

        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        Close();
      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
        //WriteProtokoll(ex.ToString(), 0);   
        Close();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Add a public property with a getter that exposes the selected item.  Now the calling code can simply use that property when ShowDialog() returns OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I can get my value with:

```
      string txt = listView1.FocusedItem.Text;
```